# How to correctly manipulate and return an array of files with node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

Given a directory containing markdown files, i.e.

```
myDir
|- fileA.md
|- fileB.md
|- fileC.md
|- fileD.md
```

I'm trying to create an array of these files, by also stripping the file extension.

I'm trying with this:

```js
var mdFiles = fs.readdir('myDir', (err, files) => {

    const filesNoExt = []

    files.forEach( file => {      
        filesNoExt.push(file.slice(0, -3)
    })
    return filesNoExt
});

console.log(mdFiles)
```

but the result of the `console.log` command is `undefined`.

If I modify this script like this (so, by adding a `console.log` inside the `readdir` function):

```js
var mdFiles = fs.readdir('myDir', (err, files) => {

    const filesNoExt = []

    files.forEach( file => {      
        filesNoExt.push(file.slice(0, -3)
    })
    console.log(filesNoExt)
});

console.log(mdFiles)
```

here is what I get:

```
undefined
[
  'fileA',
  'fileB',
  'fileC',
  'fileD'
]
```

The first line is `undefined` exactly like before, but then it is also printed the result of the `console.log` inside the function, which shows that the `filesNoExt` array is correctly populated with the stripped filenames.

**How can I correctly return the `filesNoExt` array from the `mdFiles` function, so that I can access its content also from outside?**

Answer (score 3):

The reason it's not working is because `readdir` is an asynchronous function, which means it runs in parallel to the rest of your code. If you want to block execution, use `readdirSync`:

```js
var mdFiles = fs.readdirSync('myDir');
const filesNoExt = [];
mdFiles.forEach(file => {      
    filesNoExt.push(file.slice(0, -3)
});
console.log(filesNoExt);
```

Answer (score 1):

The callback you passed to `fs.readdir` happens asynchronously (after the call stack empties), so there is no way that you can get its return value like that. In fact, the return value is ignored. You can use this:

```js
fs.readdir('myDir', (err, files) => {
    const filesNoExt = [];

    files.forEach( file => {      
        filesNoExt.push(file.slice(0, -3)
    });

    console.log(mdFiles)
});
```

Or you can use promises like this:

```js
(async ()=>{

  const mdFiles = await fs.promises.readdir('myDir');

  files.forEach( file => {      
    filesNoExt.push(file.slice(0, -3)
  });

  console.log(mdFiles);
})();
```

If you are doing other asynchronous actions (e.g. using `setTimeout`) you should *not* use the synchronous variants of `fs` functions (like `fs.readdirSync`) because they will block the program (main thread) while executing the action.